# MongoDB how to find documents by searching a Mixed Schema field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a search text like "America". I have following mongo document:

```
[
 {
  "name": "Car Loan",
  "details": [
   {
       "Bank": "America First",
       "Location": "USA"
   }
 }
]
```

I use Mongoose and I can find a single schema like "name" using this:

> .find({"name":{ "$regex": req.query.searchText, "$options": "i" } })

Is there a similar way to search for a text inside a mixed schema like "details"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) specifying all the fields :

```
db.text.find({
    $or: [
        { "details.Bank": { "$regex": "America", "$options": "i" } },
        { "details.Location": { "$regex": "America", "$options": "i" } }
    ]
})
```

Or you can use [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) feature with built-in case insensitivity feature, you have to create [text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) on your array field item :

```
db.text.createIndex({
    "details.Bank": "text",
    "details.Location": "text"
})
```

and find with [`$text` `$search`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) :

```
db.text.find({
    $text: {
        $search: "usa"
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I used a modification of the second solution of creating index and it solved my query.

Comment: I had another question related to this, I don't know if you might be able to help me with. The above 'createIndex' function does give me results for search text for just the values like 'America First' or 'USA'. What if I also wanted to include the keys like 'Bank' and 'Location' into my index and then use that to find the documents. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Do you mean you want to search only by Bank or only by Location (inside `details`) ?

Comment: No I have documents with various different keys in details. So, I want if I have "Bank" as my search text, it should match the above document I wrote.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to define all the keys separately with text index, I think multi-key doesn't work with `text` index and when `text` is used in aggregation, it has to be the first pipeline stage. So if you want to use `text` index you have to be careful when you define your model

Comment: hey, how can i implement index text to implement searching within those documents that matches a certain conditon.